# how to send email with attachment from server path in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I need to attach files with my email in asp.net. the files are uploaded in the Server.path. but I don't know how to add this with my email please guide me
My code

```
public static void SendEmail_With_Attachment(String ToEmail, String Subj, string Message, string sourcePath)
{
    //reading sender email credential from web.config file
    HostAdd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"].ToString();
    FromEmailid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMail"].ToString();
    Pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();

    //creating the object of mailmessage
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(FromEmailid);
    mailMessage.Subject = Subj;
    mailMessage.Body = Message;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToEmail));
    FileStream fStream;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
    foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
        fStream = File.OpenRead(sourcePath + "\\" + files.Name);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fStream, files.Name));
        fStream.Close();
    }

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = HostAdd;

    //network and security related credentia
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
    NetworkCred.UserName = mailMessage.From.Address;
    NetworkCred.Password = Pass;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

this code working very fine without attachment, bout with attachment i get this error:
Failure sending mail.

Comment: If you got as far as you did, I think the attachments isn't your issue (though you should be using `using` statements for your stream). We need more detail about the exception you're getting. Is there an error code or inner exception? Are you using Gmail for the host by any chance?

Comment: Are your attachments too large?

Comment: yes,I'm using Gmail for the host. error occur in line smtp.Send(mailMessage);

Comment: no,attachment size about 10kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to **Open** files.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
{
   if (file.Exists) 
   {
      mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.FullName));
   }
}
```

Comment: can you help me: why I try to Directory.Delete(sourcePath, true); I get error The process cannot access the file ' ' because it is being used by another process. how can I solved this

Comment: Could you please open a new question with the code and post the link here?